# How do I set a default drive / folder when opening windows explorer from some JS

Tags: javascript, jsp

The JS opens windows explorer, lets the user select a file and then opens the file. I want to default it to look in the same folder each time.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFilename()
{
<!-- open the file -->
var thefile = document.getElementById('thefile');
window.open(thefile.value,'mywindow','width=400,height=200')
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
<!-- get the filename -->               
<p>FCT scanned files search screen</P>
<p>Click Browse to select file</P>
<input type="file" id="thefile" onchange="getFilename()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is impossible (at least in IE). For security reasons you are not able to change anything with a file input field. You even can't change the value of the input field via scripting (only via the dialog window).

You might be able to do this for your own browser by hacking some things in the Windows Registry, but I'm not sure at all.

Gr. Rick